# Comparing date() in sql query

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I have 5 records in mysql database and these records have recorded date within this date interval.

```
$year=2015;
$month=8;
$datefrom=1;
$dateto=31;

$startdate='$year-$month-$datefrom 00:00:00';
$enddate='$year-$month-$dateto 23:59:59';
```

So I write a query to get these records out like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM newpost WHERE email=:email AND :startdate <= poststart <= :enddate AND postapproved=1";
```

Given that `poststart` column in table newpost has SQL Datetime format like this: "Y-m-d H:i:s".

But when I changed variable $year = 2016, I still got 5 results? It should return no record. Because those 5 records are recorded between 1 - 31 August 2015.

So I thought I did something wrong in the sql query especially the comparing date part but I could not configure out how to fix it?

Please help!

Comment: As your query is wrong. You missed `AND` in it.

Comment: For one thing, variables do not get parsed in single quotes. Which may very well be the issue here.

Comment: you also have a keyword `AND/OR` missing (and something else, column) in `AND :startdate <= poststart (???) <= :enddate AND postapproved=1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `BETWEEN` in your query

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM newpost WHERE email=:email AND (poststart  BETWEEN :startmonth AND :endmonth) postapproved=1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes to wrap your date values

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM newpost WHERE email=:email AND poststart BETWEEN ':startdate' AND ':enddate' AND postapproved=1";
```

Comment: I doubt that very much.

Answer (score 0):

A couple quick things to check to make sure it's not a syntactical error:

1. Your variable names don't match up. You defined `startdate` and `enddate`, but then in the query you used `startmonth` and `endmonth`.
2. You should probably also use leading zeros in your month and day, i.e.:

   ```
   $month='08';
   $datefrom='01';
   ```